# Simple meter simulator

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port

I've created a simple python meter simulator which connects to a serial port (in my case `COM1`) listens on the serial port and takes actions based on what it receives.

I'm looking for some advice regarding:

- unnecessary / wrong logic (it looks like I've abused those `while` loops)
- code that might be rewritten in a more concise / pythonic way (maybe some methods to avoid the repeating code)
- I'm not so interested in `PEP`ing this code but any advice regarding this is welcomed.

To understand how the flow actually works:

- from a third party software (of a real meter) I send a command (let's say `read_register`)
- I'm monitoring the raw data that is written on `COM1` and I can see that the real meter sends a `bytearray` which looks like this: `?/35169984\r\n`. The raw data that is being read for this specific `bytearray` is `/ELS2\\@V8.22         \r\n`. (there might be a longer communication here, but from now on I think it's easy to figure out how the comunication works)
- after the above communication is done, on the real meter I receive a list of indexes. (in my case - I just have a file that contains the exact same indexes as the real meter sends)

Here are two pictures of:

- written data:

[image: write data]

- read data

[image: read data]

Please ask me if there's anything unclear and I'll try to provide as many details as possible.

```
import serial
import time

# configure the serial connections
serial_object = serial.Serial(
    port='COM1',
    baudrate=1200,
    parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)
serial_object.close()

dict_of_bytes = {
    'null_byte': b'',
    'new_line_byte': b'\n',
    'ack_byte': b'\x06',
    'a': b'a',
    'etx_byte': b'\x03'
}

dict_of_bytearray = {
    'init_command': b'/?35169984!\r\n',
    'second_command': b'\x06021\r\n',
    'third_command': b'\x06020\r\n'
}

dict_of_responses = {
    'init_response': b'/ELS2\\@V8.22         \r\n',
    'second_response': b'\x01P0\x02(35169984)\x03m Soll: m',
    'third_response': b'\x01P1\x02(00000000)\x03a'
}

while True:
    serial_object.open()
    print('\nListening on serial...\n\n')
    received_byte = dict_of_bytes['null_byte']
    received_bytearray = bytearray()

    while received_byte != dict_of_bytes['new_line_byte']:
        received_byte = serial_object.read(1)  # this reads byte-by-byte what it comes on COM1
        received_bytearray += received_byte # create the entire bytearray

        if received_byte == dict_of_bytes['new_line_byte']:
            break

    if received_bytearray == dict_of_bytearray['init_command']:
        serial_object.write(dict_of_responses['init_response'])
        received_byte = dict_of_bytes['null_byte']
        received_bytearray = bytearray()

        while received_byte != dict_of_bytes['new_line_byte']:
            received_byte = serial_object.read(1)
            received_bytearray += received_byte

            if received_byte == dict_of_bytes['new_line_byte']:
                break

        if received_bytearray == dict_of_bytearray['second_command']:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            serial_object.write(dict_of_responses['second_response'])
            time.sleep(0.5)
            received_byte = dict_of_bytes['null_byte']
            received_bytearray = bytearray()

            while received_byte != dict_of_bytes['a']:
                received_byte = serial_object.read(1)
                received_bytearray += received_byte

                if received_byte == dict_of_bytes['a']:
                    break

            if received_bytearray == dict_of_responses['third_response']:
                time.sleep(0.5)
                serial_object.write(dict_of_bytes['ack_byte'])
                received_byte = dict_of_bytes['null_byte']
                received_bytearray = bytearray()

                while received_byte != dict_of_bytes['etx_byte']:
                    received_byte = serial_object.read(1)
                    received_bytearray += received_byte

                    if received_byte == dict_of_bytes['etx_byte']:
                        received_bytearray += serial_object.read()
                        break

        else:
            if received_bytearray == dict_of_bytearray['third_command']:
                time.sleep(0.5)

                with open('regs.txt', 'rb') as fin:
                    bytes_from_file = fin.read()
                    serial_object.write(bytes_from_file)
                    print(bytes_from_file.decode('utf-8'))
                    print('length: ' + str(len(bytes_from_file)))
    serial_object.close()
```

Comment: I cannot elaborate enough nor am I sure of this enough to post an answer, but a generator is usually used to model input streams in Python. Pseudocode may be like `for packet in serial_input: # process packet`, to be more explicit than `while` loops

Comment: Is `serial` [pyserial](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial)?

Comment: @JoeWallis yes it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Disclaimer:*** None of this review has been tested. I've just applied some manipulation of your original code.

**Making thing more simple**

Your `dict_of_<something>` dictionnaries are constant and always used with literal strings. From my point of view, it'd be much clearer to use constants to achieve the same thing:

```
import serial
import time

# configure the serial connections
serial_object = serial.Serial(
    port='COM1',
    baudrate=1200,
    parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)
serial_object.close()

# Bytes
NULL_BYTE = b''
NEW_LINE_BYTE = b'\n'
ACK_BYTE = b'\x06'
A = b'a'
ETX_BYTE = b'\x03'

# Commands
INIT_COMMAND = b'/?35169984!\r\n'
SECOND_COMMAND = b'\x06021\r\n'
THIRD_COMMAND = b'\x06020\r\n'

# Responses
INIT_REPONSE = b'/ELS2\\@V8.22         \r\n'
SECOND_REPONSE = b'\x01P0\x02(35169984)\x03m Soll: m'
THIRD_REPONSE = b'\x01P1\x02(00000000)\x03a'

while True:
    serial_object.open()
    print('\nListening on serial...\n\n')
    received_byte = NULL_BYTE
    received_bytearray = bytearray()

    while received_byte != NEW_LINE_BYTE:
        received_byte = serial_object.read(1)  # this reads byte-by-byte what it comes on COM1
        received_bytearray += received_byte # create the entire bytearray

        if received_byte == NEW_LINE_BYTE:
            break

    if received_bytearray == INIT_COMMAND:
        serial_object.write(INIT_REPONSE)
        received_byte = NULL_BYTE
        received_bytearray = bytearray()

        while received_byte != NEW_LINE_BYTE:
            received_byte = serial_object.read(1)
            received_bytearray += received_byte

            if received_byte == NEW_LINE_BYTE:
                break

        if received_bytearray == SECOND_COMMAND:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            serial_object.write(SECOND_REPONSE)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            received_byte = NULL_BYTE
            received_bytearray = bytearray()

            while received_byte != A:
                received_byte = serial_object.read(1)
                received_bytearray += received_byte

                if received_byte == A:
                    break

            if received_bytearray == THIRD_REPONSE:
                time.sleep(0.5)
                serial_object.write(ACK_BYTE)
                received_byte = NULL_BYTE
                received_bytearray = bytearray()

                while received_byte != ETX_BYTE:
                    received_byte = serial_object.read(1)
                    received_bytearray += received_byte

                    if received_byte == ETX_BYTE:
                        received_bytearray += serial_object.read()
                        break

        else:
            if received_bytearray == THIRD_COMMAND:
                time.sleep(0.5)

                with open('regs.txt', 'rb') as fin:
                    bytes_from_file = fin.read()
                    serial_object.write(bytes_from_file)
                    print(bytes_from_file.decode('utf-8'))
                    print('length: ' + str(len(bytes_from_file)))
    serial_object.close()
```

**Don't repeat yourself**

There is a piece of code you have in different places. It might be worth extracting it in a function on its own:

```
def get_bytearray(serial, ending_value):
    received_byte = NULL_BYTE
    received_bytearray = bytearray()
    while received_byte != ending_value:
        received_byte = serial_object.read(1)
        received_bytearray += received_byte
        if received_byte == ending_value:
            break
    return received_bytearray

while True:
    serial_object.open()
    print('\nListening on serial...\n\n')
    received_bytearray = get_bytearray(serial_object, NEW_LINE_BYTE)

    if received_bytearray == INIT_COMMAND:
        serial_object.write(INIT_REPONSE)
        received_bytearray = get_bytearray(serial_object, NEW_LINE_BYTE)

        if received_bytearray == SECOND_COMMAND:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            serial_object.write(SECOND_REPONSE)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            received_bytearray = get_bytearray(serial_object, A)

            if received_bytearray == THIRD_REPONSE:
                time.sleep(0.5)
                serial_object.write(ACK_BYTE)
                received_bytearray = get_bytearray(serial_object, ETX_BYTE)
        else:
            if received_bytearray == THIRD_COMMAND:
                time.sleep(0.5)

                with open('regs.txt', 'rb') as fin:
                    bytes_from_file = fin.read()
                    serial_object.write(bytes_from_file)
                    print(bytes_from_file.decode('utf-8'))
                    print('length: ' + str(len(bytes_from_file)))
    serial_object.close()
```

**Re-write your function**

Now that some part of the logic is extracted in a function, it is much easier to think about it and/or to rewrite it.

In your code, I'd simply write :

```
def get_bytearray(serial, ending_value):
    received_bytearray = bytearray()
    while True:
        received_byte = serial_object.read(1)
        received_bytearray += received_byte
        if received_byte == ending_value:
            return received_bytearray
```

(Note that is also removes the need for a `NULL_BYTE` constant).
(I *might* add other comments later on)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'll try your solution tomorrow and let you know if everything is ok. Feel free to edit this with other ideas when you have some free time.

Answer (score 2):

Since Josay has mentioned all the points that I was going to raise, I'll just say:

`serial_object` is usable in a `with` and it makes little sense why you are manually `open`ing and `close`ing this object. Instead I'd just wrap the `while True` in a `with`.

Such as, Note I've not tested this, but I checked the source and `Serial` has both `__enter__` and `__exit__`:

```
serial_object = serial.Serial(
    port='COM1',
    baudrate=1200,
    parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)
with serial_object:
    while True:
        ...
```

And then use Josay's points.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It does its job as you said. Cheers.